# jQuery/js event on click on container but not on element IN the container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a click-event on a container, but *not* when I click on an element within the container:

```
$('.container').click(function(event) {
    history.back(1);
});
```

But the history.back() should not be called, when I click on

```
<div class="container"><a href="URL">Link</a></div>
```

Is it possible to exclude the link from the container-event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('.container').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div' ) {
    // code
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no clue why, but the code's working perfectly fine, thanks!

Comment: Anonymous downvoter care to comment? Is my answer somehow wrong?

Answer (score 2):

use `event.stopPropagation();` in click event handler:

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Why do you have both?

Comment: @Ian:actually return false is not required. `stopPropagation` will handle it

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$('.container').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target === event.currentTarget) history.back(1);
    //(event.target === this) => Equivalent.
});
```